# Gitlab merge request default name

Tags: gitlab, merge-request

When a merge request it's created from an issue, this title it's generated:

```
Draft: Resolve "issue"
```

How can I modify the default behavoiur? Ideally to me should be fine just

```
Draft: Issue
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to change this precise default behavior for MR titles. However, there are a couple open feature requests related to this capability: [#16080](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/16080) and [#22209](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/22209).

The closest thing would be to [create a default template](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/description_templates.html#set-a-default-template-for-merge-requests-and-issues) for MRs. However, this is only for the description, not the title.

Comment: As I thought. It's a nonsense though.